# Issues installing Angular with existing project

Tags: node.js, .net, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Angular and am trying to setup my dev environment. My Win10 machine has NodeJS v16.2 installed. I'm also using VSCode.

I cloned an existing Angular web project that uses Angular Core 14.0.0 from a git repo. Using the NodeJS command prompt, I navigated into the Angular project folder and tried the command npm install. I got the error below and I think its saying I already have Angular 14.3.0 installed. I however uninstalled it, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

> ## npm resolution error report
>
> While resolving: @angular/http@7.2.16 Found: @angular/core@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/core   @angular/core@"^14.0.0" from the root
> project   peer @angular/core@"14.3.0" from @angular/animations@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/animations
> @angular/animations@"^14.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/animations@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.7
> node_modules/@angular/material
> @angular/material@"^14.2.5" from the root project
> peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
> @angular/platform-browser@"^14.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.3.0" from @angular/forms@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/forms
> @angular/forms@"^14.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/forms@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.7
> node_modules/@angular/material
> @angular/material@"^14.2.5" from the root project
> peer @angular/forms@">=14.1.0" from ngx-editor@15.3.0
> node_modules/ngx-editor
> ngx-editor@"^15.3.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/platform-browser@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/material@14.2.7
> node_modules/@angular/material
> @angular/material@"^14.2.5" from the root project
> peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.3.0" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^14.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/platform-browser@"14.3.0" from @angular/router@14.3.0
> node_modules/@angular/router
> @angular/router@"^14.0.0" from the root project
> peer @angular/platform-browser@">=14.1.0" from ngx-editor@15.3.0
> node_modules/ngx-editor
> ngx-editor@"^15.3.0" from the root project   peer @angular/core@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.7
> node_modules/@angular/cdk
>
> > Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

> {   "code": "ERESOLVE",   "edge": {
> "type": "peer",
> "name": "@angular/core",
> "spec": "7.2.16",
> "error": "INVALID",
> "from": {
> "name": "@angular/http",
> "version": "7.2.16",
> "location": "node_modules/@angular/http",
> "isWorkspace": false,
> "dependents": [
> {
> "type": "prod",
> "name": "@angular/http",
> "spec": "^7.2.16",
> "from": {
> "location": "C:\git\WebApp\UI"
> }
> }
> ]
> }   },

I tried uninstalling Angular/CLI using npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

I also tried a npm cache clean --force and npm cache verify.

I checked my windows appdata folder and deleted any Angular folders.

I've tried installing Angular 14.0.0 to match the project, but I still get the same error.

If I create a brand new project everything works fine.

Comment: delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` to resolve it

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately that didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: in cmd before you do run `set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` command

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1- install npm-check-updates globally

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

2- update package.json

```
ncu -u
```

3- install packages

```
npm install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache of the NPM using
**npm cache clean --force**

Or you can try to delete the node_modules and then do npm i again maybe that might work.